# Flutter: How to add suggestion text on keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I want to add a custom word on keyboard as suggestion.
The logic is to show a list of suggestion words for some TextFormFields

```
TextFormField(
 controller: controller,
 textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
 onTapOutside: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
 decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: hintText),
 onChanged: onChanged,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **[AutofillHints](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html)** for suggesting hints on keyboard.

Example :

```
 TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.name], // use this line
            ...
          )
```